# SQL Join BETWEEN Dates Counting Issue

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

Difficult issue to explain, so please bear with me.

I have two tables:

1) A breakdown by Date and whether they were on Basic that day (Y/N)

```
ID      Date        Basic_Days
5423    2019-02-03  1
5423    2019-02-04  0
5423    2019-02-05  1
5423    2019-02-06  1
5423    2019-02-07  1
5423    2019-02-08  1
5423    2019-02-09  0
5423    2019-02-10  0
5423    2019-02-11  0
5423    2019-02-12  0
5423    2019-02-13  0
5423    2019-02-14  1
5423    2019-02-15  1
5423    2019-02-16  1
```

2) A breakdown of different date periods by order

```
EPI_Start_Date  EPI_End_Date     ID     EPI_ORDER
2019-02-03      2019-02-04       5423   1
2019-02-04      2019-02-15       5423   2
2019-02-15      2019-02-16       5423   3
```

What I am trying to do, is to attribute the individual days, into their respective EPI_ORDER, but without double counting days.

**Ideal output is:**

```
Basic_Days  EPI_Start_Date  EPI_End_Date    ID      EPIORDER
1           2019-02-03      2019-02-04      5423    1
5           2019-02-04      2019-02-15      5423    2
2           2019-02-15      2019-02-16      5423    3
```

**What I have tried so far:**

The query I have started almost gets me there. But I would like a way to handle the last date correctly.

```
SELECT 
 SUM(CAST(p.Basic_Days AS int)) AS Basic_Days
, x.EPI_Start_Date
, x.EPI_End_Date
, p.ID
, x.EPIORDER


FROM *SNIP* AS x

    INNER JOIN *SNIP* table leapfrog join here, unnecessary for display purposes AS cc

    INNER JOIN *SNIP* AS p 
    ON  p.ID = cc.ID

    AND (   (p.[Date] BETWEEN x.EPI_Start_Date AND x.EPI_End_Date) 

        AND (p.[Date] <> x.EPI_End_Date) ) --this was my effort into not counting the last day on each, but it doesn't work for the very final day, where I DO want it.


WHERE p.ID = '5423' --testing

GROUP BY  EPI_Start_Date
        , EPI_End_Date
        , x.EPIORDER
        , ID
```

**My actual output gives me:**

```
Basic_Days  EPI_Start_Date  EPI_End_Date    ID      EPIORDER
1           2019-02-03      2019-02-04      5423    1
5           2019-02-04      2019-02-15      5423    2
1           2019-02-15      2019-02-16      5423    3
```

You can see the final row only has 1 Basic_Days. But I'd like it to be 2 Basic_Days.

I feel I'm not too far away, but I just need to tweak the AND Statements in my Join.

Any help appreciated! Hopefully I've explained well enough to make some sense?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0):

Change your BETWEEN to

```
p.[Date] >= x.EPI_Start_Date AND  p.[Date] < x.EPI_End_Date
```

BETWEEN is inclusive at both ends, that is to say it behaves like this, which will double count your days:

```
--don't want the end date compare to be <=
p.[Date] >= x.EPI_Start_Date AND  p.[Date] <= x.EPI_End_Date
```

You can remove `(p.[Date] <> x.EPI_End_Date)` too

Lastly, I'd like to point out that your ideal output is inconsistent - for most of your ideal output you've said you don't want the records falling on the end date to be included in that band, and then suddenly for the last record, you do want it in the band. It's possible to craft a query that takes care of this, but it's inconsistent data modelling, to have 2 rows that don't include a value in their band, and then one row that suddenly does include a value another row wouldn't include "just because there isn't another band for it" - decide if this is really what you want, because next time you run that report, the "count of basic days between 15th and 16th" will drop from 2 to 1, just because another band (eg from 16 to 21) has been added..

Something like this will spuriously include the last row in the wrong band "just because it's the last row":

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT t.*, MAX(EPI_END_DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY ID) as max_end_date FROM date_ranges_table) x
ON 
  p.ID = x.ID AND
  p.[Date] >= x.EPI_Start_Date AND (p.[Date] < x.EPI_End_Date OR p.Date = x.max_end_date)
```

Comment: I see your logic, but I still get the same results. Basic Days 1,5,1 instead of 1,5,2.

Comment: Thanks. But the inconsistent ideal output is what I'm aiming for. I need to handle that last entry differently somehow. Apologies if that wasn't clear in the original question :)

Comment: You should really put it in another band. It belongs in the "16 to 21" band, not the "15 to 16" band. Add another row to your table, either literally by writing data into the table with a high end date, or virtually with `SELECT * FROM date_ranges UNION ALL SELECT ID, MAX(end_date), '9999-12-31', MAX(epi_order)+1 FROM date_ranges GROUP BY id`. If you're going to be paying someone etc based on this report, then someone is going to wonder why the amounts paid don't line up with next months account for days worked etc when the report banding assignments change

Comment: There are 8 days in total to be divided out. With my current method, only 7 actually get accounted for. The date bands are set and can't be adjusted, so I can't create an extra band for the spare day. As it stands, the day of 16th isn't landing anywhere.

Comment: That's because it doesn't belong anywhere in the date ranges you've declared.. but I've edited the post to indicate how to hack it into the last band